# Can't get selenium to click an element

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to simulate a few clicks for my new program but I'm stuck on the last thing!

I've managed to make selenium open the page and click on the checkbox which shows a rectangle popup with 9 buttons inside it. The only problem is clicking the buttons inside the pop up! I've checked the xpath a few times but Selenium says "No such element"

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class test {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
        driver.get("http://www.runelocus.com/top-rsps-list/vote-1858-GrinderScape%20-%20New%20Website%20and%20Great%20Updates!/");
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']/div[5]")).click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#rc-imageselect-target > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)")).click();
    }


}
```

Link to the problem: http://www.runelocus.com/top-rsps-list/vote-1858-GrinderScape%20-%20New%20Website%20and%20Great%20Updates!/

**EDIT:**
It creates the new elements after you click the checkbox. How would I click them?

Comment: You are trying to make a robot that clicks the "I am not a robot checkbox"?

Comment: You need to switch to that pop-up. As it can be new window.

Comment: Yeah then I screen shot the captcha and send it to a captcha solving service.

Comment: Sorry.. but no help for you

Comment: @mk08 I've tried switching frames but that didn't work :/ I'll post the link and surrounding html now

Comment: Indeed it is in iframe. Posting my answer. It is working now.

Comment: can you post the solution too. if you've resolved it

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3):

Element you are trying to click is in iframe. We need to switch explicitly to that iframe for selenium to locate that element. Below code worked for me. (Please format Xpath in better readable format.)

```
    driver.get("http://www.runelocus.com/top-rsps-list/vote-1858-GrinderScape%20-%20New%20Website%20and%20Great%20Updates!/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement iframeSwitch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div/div/section/div/article/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/div/iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframeSwitch);
    System.out.println("Switched");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class=recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already switched frames and can click the checkbox its just the pop-up what opens after you click the checkbox. I need to click one of the 9 images in the pop-up.

Comment: Am I missing that popup? Somehow I can not see the window with 9 check boxes. It just stays on the page when you click on `I am not robot`.